# What are the suggested alternatives for Class<T>.isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)?

Tags: java, performance, reflection

Currently I am doing the profiling to a piece of code. During the profiling, I discovered that  this very method call,

```
Class<T>.isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)
```

takes up to quite amount of the entire time.

Because this is a method from reflection, it takes a lot of time compared to normal keywords or method calls. I am wondering if there are some good alternatives for this method calls?

Comment: Why don't you explain more about how this method is being used, and why static type-checking won't work.

Comment: Actually, it is used in various ways. One of the ways is that it examines the Class<T> type passed in through a method argument to see if the type matches certain qualifications. I would like to know if I will have to rewrite the method signature and change all the related invocations.

Comment: Are you using generics? Generic wildcards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "[I]t examines the Class type
>   passed in through a method argument to
>   see if the type matches certain
>   qualifications."

To me, that implies that the method argument should be required to implement a particular interface or inherit from a particular class.  Keep in mind, the interface could be a marker like [RandomAccess](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html).  I realize changing your API may not be an option.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an object whose class you are retrieving, you can replace this with:

```
obj instanceof ClassName
```

but I wouldn't say its faster. Actually, I doubt this causes any problems with the program execution. Don't overoptimize.

Comment: +1 for doubting if this makes a real difference. How much time are we talking here?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this effects you, but I think it is worth noting that in the early days of Java 5, isAssignableFrom had [significant performance problems](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6461827) that were later corrected. I couldn't find if the fix was backported to Java 5, but it certainly went into Java 6.

Additionally, the [Sun JVM Performance Wiki](http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PerformanceTechniques) points out that **Class.isInstance** and **Class.isAssignableFrom** are as performant as **instanceof**.

So if you are on Java 6 or later, there doesn't seem to be an alternative for **Class.isAssignableFrom** that will be faster than what is already there.